# How to toggle active tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

I mean like a accordion navigation first click open it second click hide it

demo link : `http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/dGKEjy`

you can see above link

```
$("ul.otel-filtre-fiyat-tab li").click(function(){
        /*
            $(this).parents(".otel-tekli-listeleme").find(".otel-full-detay").slideToggle();
        */
        var number = $(this).index();
        $("ul.otel-filtre-fiyat-tab li").removeClass("tab-aktif-hover");
        $(this).parents(".otel-tekli-listeleme").find(".otel-tab-icerik").hide().eq(number).slideDown("fast");
        $(this).parents(".otel-tekli-listeleme").find("ul.otel-filtre-fiyat-tab li").eq(number).addClass("tab-aktif-hover");
        return false;
    });
```

you can click marked area

[image: you can click marked area]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
$(this).parents(".otel-tekli-listeleme").find(".otel-tab-icerik").hide().eq(number).slideDown("fast");
```

I removed `hide` method and I used `slideToggle` instead of `slideDown`.

```
$(this).parents(".otel-tekli-listeleme").find(".otel-tab-icerik").eq(number).slideToggle("fast");
```

I changed also the last line:

```
$(this).parents(".otel-tekli-listeleme").find("ul.otel-filtre-fiyat-tab li").eq(number).toggleClass("tab-aktif-hover");
```

In this way the border color will be removed if the tab is close. You need also to remove the line with `removeClass`. Result:

```
$("ul.otel-filtre-fiyat-tab li").click(function(){
    var number = $(this).index();

    $(this).parents(".otel-tekli-listeleme").find(".otel-tab-icerik").not(':eq(' + number + ')').slideUp("fast");
    $(this).parents(".otel-tekli-listeleme").find("ul.otel-filtre-fiyat-tab li").not(':eq(' + number + ')').removeClass("tab-aktif-hover");

    $(this).parents(".otel-tekli-listeleme").find(".otel-tab-icerik").eq(number).slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).parents(".otel-tekli-listeleme").find("ul.otel-filtre-fiyat-tab li").eq(number).toggleClass("tab-aktif-hover");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I understand thanks to you..so so much greetings.I am grateful

Comment: but now when I clicked first tab its work but another tabs not working

Comment: I wil check as soon as possible

Comment: @yedincifirat Ok I added a piece of code to solve the issue